# Юнит-тесты и Tuple

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, tuple

После того как прогоняю этот тест:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    int[] input = new int[5] {6,7,8,9,10};
    List<int> group1 = new List<int>() {10,7,6};
    List<int> group2 = new List<int>() {9,8};
    var result = Tuple.Create(group1, group2);
    var output = Program.dividetoequalgroups(input);
    Assert.AreEqual(result, output);
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

> Message: Сбой Assert.AreEqual. Ожидается: <(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32], System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32])>. Фактически: <(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32], System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32])>.

Сам метод проверял несколько раз на такие же значения через консоль, все было верно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Зачем вообще вы собираете кортеж? Почему наоборот не разобрать его?

Comment: Потому что непонятно как тестовый фреймворк справится с коллекциями внутри кортежа. Просто для коллекций там перегрузка есть (вроде)

Comment: Я имею ввиду: `var (output1, output2) = Program.dividetoequalgroups(input);` и потом `Assert.AreEqual(group1, output1);` и `Assert.AreEqual(group2, output2);`

Comment: а как вообще сравнение для ссылочных типов тут реализовано? сравнение ссылок или значений?

Comment: Собственно, а что вас удивляет? Вы сравниваете кортежи, внутри которых ссылочные типы, указывающие на разные ссылки. Следовательно, эти туплы не равны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью разбора кортежа:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    int[] input = new int[5] {6,7,8,9,10};
    List<int> group1 = new List<int>() {10,7,6};
    List<int> group2 = new List<int>() {9,8};
    var temp = Program.dividetoequalgroups(input);
    List<int> output1 = temp.Item1;
    List<int> output2 = temp.Item2;
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(output1, group1);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(output2, group2);
}
```

(P.S Спасибо Андрею NOP)

Comment: `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(output2, group2);` потеряли